# Facebook stuck notification "cast device not connected"

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, notifications, facebook, lg-g3

I have a notification that **can not** be removed,created by the facebook app with message "Cast Device Not Connected".
I did notice that it happens any time I open a facebook video where catable device is available. (I use lg g3 with Lollipop 5.0) 
 
How can I remove this notification?

[image]

Comment: If you Force-stop facebook, It will clear the notification. Just Go settings > apps> Facebook > Force Stop > Accept the warning.

Comment: Yeah, but when I'll open the app again the notification comes back

Comment: You can Disable **all** notifications for Facebook. Other than that, No idea- I Don't use the app, I just Login Via chrome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoted from [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-fix-that-broken-chromecast-notification-facebook-1788382720), referencing [Android Police](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/10/29/that-annoying-chromecast-notification-is-coming-from-the-facebook-app-heres-how-to-fix-it/#disqus_thread):

> If you’re using the Facebook app—and there are plenty of reasons not to—you might have noticed a weird, broken Chromecast notification in your shade recently. Here’s what’s causing it and how to fix it.
>
> As Android Police discovered, this notification is being caused by a bug in the way Facebook handles videos. The app now supports [casting videos](http://lifehacker.com/remains-of-the-day-you-can-now-cast-videos-from-facebo-1787763115) which is nice, but when you play a video, the notification you see above appears with two buttons that do nothing. The only way to get rid of the notification is to force close the app.
>
> According to the site, this is a bug with version 100.0.0.20.70 of the Facebook app, but the problem is not present in the beta app, version 101.0.0.10.70, which you can download from [APK Mirror here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/facebook/facebook-101-0-0-10-70-release/). Alternatively, you can download the stripped down Facebook Lite from [APK Mirror here](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/facebook-2/lite/). Or, just use the mobile site like we’ve recommended for ages.